# Valgrind 'uninitialised value' dependency doesn't reference my code

Tags: c++, valgrind

This valgrind output is confusing me, because it doesn't seem to reference my code, and I've gotten it on multiple programs I wrote using the STL, although there are no HEAP SUMMARY errors:

```
$ valgrind -v --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./hellostl

...

==7989== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7989==    at 0x4017AA6: index (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x4007A12: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x4008304: _dl_map_object (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x400181D: map_doit (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x400E985: _dl_catch_error (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x40010EF: do_preload (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x40039D7: dl_main (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x40152B7: _dl_sysdep_start (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x4004E94: _dl_start (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x4001637: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==7989==    at 0x4003961: dl_main (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==
==7989== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7989==    at 0x4017AAB: index (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x4007A12: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x4008304: _dl_map_object (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x400181D: map_doit (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x400E985: _dl_catch_error (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x40010EF: do_preload (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x40039D7: dl_main (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x40152B7: _dl_sysdep_start (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x4004E94: _dl_start (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==    by 0x4001637: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==7989==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==7989==    at 0x4003961: dl_main (in /lib64/ld-2.17.so)
```

Is it possible that I'm using an outdated version of something (e.g. compiler, valgrind...)?

**Edit**: Simple code which is triggering the bug:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<int> foo;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        foo.push_back( i );

    for (auto it = foo.begin();
        it != foo.end();
        ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code that causes this, so that others can try to reproduce it

Comment: Not all the standard platform library code is "clean", unfortunately. You may have to install some suppression rules for valgrind. `libdl` may be one such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic linking library is notorious for causing Valgrind warnings. The one you observe is actually a very common one. You cannot fix this warning, but you can add a suppression rule if it annoys you.

To further elaborate, what happens here is before your program is run the C++ standard library is dynamically linked. If you check your binary with `ldd`, you should see a line like this:

```
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa0e2f72000)
```

If you would statically link this library, your program would run without dynamic linking and the warnings would disappear.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm my assumption that it was STL anathema and not something on my end. Thanks.

Comment: One more question if you can, so I am understanding this correctly: there is some code running (which dynamically links stl libraries into my code) in the linking phase which has some uninitialized value problems, correct?

Comment: Exactly. Here is a good overview of what happens when an ELF binary is loaded: http://linuxgazette.net/84/hawk.html